# How to pass a value from JavaScript to code behind?

Tags: javascript, c#, code-behind

I want get a value from js to code behind but the value is always an empty string.

I tried to pass the value from js to a label with `runat="server"` specified but in vain.

**html:**

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="Val1"/>
```

**js:**

```
document.getElementById("Val1").value = MyFunction();

function MyFunction() 
{
    var value = "111";
}
```

**code behind:**

```
protected void sss(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string aa = Val1.Value;
}
```

Comment: If its in an input, does that mean its in a form?  If it is, just submit the form and you can get the value that way

Comment: How do you try to pass it? You don't show anything related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
var val = document.getElementById('<%=val1.Client ID%>');
val.value= "111';
```

In your cs use `val1.value`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the Session to return your data.

In js:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('Val1', '111');
```

In code behind:

```
int Val1 = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Val1"]);
```